# An obsolete comment I flagged was instantly deleted- what gives?

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, comment-flags, obsolete-flags

I got a notification that someone suggested an edit to an answer I wrote (*TL:DR; I rejected it as it was making an unnecessary change to the URL*). I then [went to the actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824013/redirecting-in-htaccess-with-advanced-method) and found that the author of the question was the one who suggested the edit & had changed the link in their question too (*strange, but not what I'm asking about here*).

I saw an obsolete comment addressing me and was along the lines of:

> Please don't badger users to accept your answer.

Fair enough.

However I flagged it as "obsolete", and then the comment *vanished*. My flag history for the question states that the flag was marked as "helpful" (as well as the aged-away flag on the actual question):

[image]

It can't have been a reviewer since the deletion was instant (*[could've  been Shog](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27063278#27063278)*), and as the comment was old it's highly unlikely that the owner of the comment deleted it.

Do comments starting with "Please don't" instantly get deleted upon an obsolete flag, or was there some other unforeseen force at play here?

[bluefeet has said that](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4236179#4236179) this is to do with the blacklist of words, but so far the behaviour has been unreproducible.

Comment: Try flagging the comment above

Comment: @NormalHuman Flagged, your comment's still present.

Comment: So the regex is more picky;  without knowing the exact text of that comment we can't reproduct it here.

Comment: @NormalHuman [According to bluefeet, it was because of the blacklisted word "accept"](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4236179#4236179), might not be active on Meta.

Comment: 95‰ sure it was the accept that did it. There might be some other heuristic required to be eligible but accepting is the main thing. Even custom flags would auto validate and delete comments in this case.

Comment: @Flexo I think it could've been the combination of "Please accept" (as mentioned in the question, we tried to reproduce the behaviour and couldn't).