# Flagging obsolete comments; repercussions to the user

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags, obsolete-flags

I just noticed that after I had deleted a couple of my own 'too chatty' comments and went to flag the 'chatty' responses as 'obsolete' (they were now referring to portions of a conversation that no longer existed), the comment(s) were removed immediately. tbh, I don't know if the accompanying comment was immediately removed because it was a response to a deleted comment or some content reason (I didn't write it down before it got deleted).

What repercussions are being handed blindly to the user in these cases? Should they be nudged to delete the flagged comments themselves before a profile 'black mark' is assigned to them? Does a profile 'black mark' get assigned to them?

---

<sup>Related:</sup>
    <sub>► [Why do comment flags sometimes take immediate effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266161/why-do-comment-flags-sometimes-take-immediate-effect)

    ► [An obsolete comment I flagged was instantly deleted- what gives?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310965/an-obsolete-comment-i-flagged-was-instantly-deleted-what-gives)

    ► [Flagging a whole comment thread as obsolete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254853/flagging-a-whole-comment-thread-as-obsolete)</sub>

Comment: There's nothing automatic here. A moderator when handling the flags might think "Umm... I'm having to delete a lot of non-constructive/potentially rude flags from this user recently... what's going on here?" but apart from that - comment flags don't really count.

Comment: @JonClements - I think that *'There's nothing automatic here'*  and *'comment flags don't really count.'* answers any concerns that I may have had.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, when certain keywords are present that the system interprets as offensive or inappropiate, single offensive/rude comment flags will automatically delete comments.

In this and the vast majority of other cases however, a moderator handled the flags and took action appropiately. There is no "blind power given to the userbase" in this case.

For the vast majority of comment flags, a moderator handles deletion and (if applicable) other penalties.

Take note that "too chatty" or "obsolete" comments usually don't get penalised (they're merely deleted)

Comment: With regard to terminology, I believe I've read somewhere that starting a comment with *'Please don't...'* can initiate an immediate removal on an obsolete flag. However, I find it hard to categorize that into one of *'offensive or inappropiate [sic], single offensive/rude'*.